# In lotus notes script i need complete logic for subtracting thirty days from current date

Tags: lotus-notes

In lotus notes script i need complete logic for subtracting thirty days from current date in CCYYMMDD format and I want to print this date using print statement so that I would see the result. I need full version of the lotus notes script including definition and data type of all variables used. I tried using many ways either I get empty results or data type mismatch while printing. I need your help please. Thank you

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but please show your attempts.

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_ADJUSTDAY_METHOD.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim dt As New NotesDateTime("")
dt.SetNow
dt.SetAnyTime
dt.AdjustDay -30
Print Format(dt.LSLocalTime, "YYYYMMDD")
```